# Autosize Windows Form with DataGridView in TabControl does not work

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tabcontrol, dock, autosize

I'm using VS 2012 with Visual Basic and Windows Forms. I have a TabControl with 3 Tabs and a DataGridView in each.

- I set the Dock Property of the DataGridViews inside the TabControl to  'Fill'.
- FormBorderStyle of the main window is Sizable
- The TabControl has anchors to Top, Bottom, Left and Right
- There are Buttons on the right side (Picture: http://s29.postimg.org/l43pq3rqf/Screenshot_2015_03_03_12_00_30.png)

**My Problem is:**
When I'm trying to resize the window its just flickering and not changing its size. Does anybody know where the Problem could be. 
Sorry if I didn't give enough Information.

Regards
Sebastian Hoelzl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you set form size maximize?

Comment: Set TabControl size of windows size

Comment: Do you know if TabControls can only be used filling the whole window? Or is it possible to put them in a kind of container for autosize?

Comment: You can use panel also it have AutoSize Property.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Sorry I can't upvote you. I'm new in the Forum and I need a minimum reputation of 15 to upvote ;)